# Spark Scala Datasets using Java Classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am creating a Spark application using the Scala binding. But some of my model's (classes) are written in Java. When I try to create a Dataset based on Scala Case Class, it works fine and all the columns are visible when I do `show()`. But when I create a Dataset based on a Java Class all the columns are packed in a single column named `value`.

**Scala Case Class Example:**

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

Execution:

```scala
sqlContext.createDataset(Seq(Person("abcd", 10))).show()
```

Output:

`name    |     age`

`abcd    |     10`

**Java Class Example:**

```java
class Person {
  public String name;
  public int age;
  public Person (String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

Execution:

```scala
sqlContext.createDataset(Seq(Person("abcd", 10))).show()
```

Output:

`value`

`[01 00 63 6F 6D 2...]`

Are we not suppose to use Java classes as models with Spark Scala app? How do we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Java classes to create Datasets but you need to explictly define bean for that class (works like that in java). In addition you need to define getter/setter methods to define bean and your class definition should have public keyword(spark complains about some compliation errors). Hope it works okay for you.

**Class**

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public Person (String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

**Execution**

```
implicit val personEncoder = Encoders.bean(classOf[Person])
sql.createDataset(Seq(new Person("abcd", 10))).show()
```

**Result**

```
+---+----+
|age|name|
+---+----+
| 10|abcd|
+---+----+
```