# Store POJOs to a Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, javabeans, pojo

I'm connecting with *Zeppelin* to my rest web-service, that returns cities, through *OpenAPI*:

```scala
import java.util.Map;

import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.model.Commune;
import fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.api.CogControllerApi;

var serviceCodeOfficielGeographique: CogControllerApi = new CogControllerApi();

var communes: Map[String, Commune] = 
    serviceCodeOfficielGeographique.obtenirCommunesUsingGET(2022);
```

it returns satisfactory results:

```
communes: java.util.Map[String,fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.model.Commune] =
{62001=class Commune {
    arrondissement: 627
    codeCanton: 6217
    codeCommune: 62001
    codeCommuneParente: null
    codeDepartement: 62
    codeEPCI: 246200364
    codeRegion: 32
    collectiviteOutremer: false
    nomCommune: Ablain-Saint-Nazaire
    nomMajuscules: ABLAIN SAINT NAZAIRE
    population: null
    sirenCommune: 216200014
 ...
```

I'd like to store the cities (the values of this map, that I'll catch with a `communes.values()`) to a `Dataset[Commune]`.

But I wonder how to do this.
I've attempted:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._

var datasetCommunes = spark.createDataset(communes, Encoders[Commune]);
```

under *Zeppelin*, but received the message:

```
<console>:96: error: object Encoders does not take type parameters.
       var datasetCommunes = spark.createDataset(communes, Encoders[Commune]);
```

I don't now how to write my statement.

---

Thanks for your advice below, @Gael_J.
I've attempted it, that way (because `map.values()` returns, in Java, a `Collection<Commune>` that I have first to convert to a `java.util.List`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import scala.collection.mutable._;
import spark.implicits._

var communeList: ArrayBuffer[Commune] = new ArrayBuffer[Commune];
communes.values().stream().forEach(commune => communeList.append(commune));

var datasetCommunes = communeList.toSeq.toDS();
```

But I'm receiving the error:

```
error: value toDS is not a member of Seq[fr.ecoemploi.application.etude.swagger.model.Commune]
       var datasetCommunes = communeList.toSeq.toDS();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Commune` is a case class, you should be able to benefit from automatic `Encoder`s with something like this:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

val ds = communes.values().toSeq().toDS()
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my message to reflect the attempt I did. But it replies that Seq doesn't have the toDS() method.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't works because what the rest API sends is Java classes? And not case classes?

Comment: Likely yes. I don't know how Spark can handle Java classes. If you're going to work with Spark in Scala, it might be worth converting these to case classes anyway. Or maybe use Spark Java in the 1st place?

Comment: I fact, I wasn't clever: instead of asking `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to generate _Java_ stub classes for me, it was better to ask it generate some _Scala_ ones! Furthermore, they are conveniently case classes.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to @GaëlJ's answer that if `Commune` is a POJO then it should be a bean and you should manually define its encoder

```
import spark.implicits._

implicit val enc = Encoders.bean(classOf[Commune])

Seq(new Commune(...)).toDS()
```

[Spark Scala Datasets using Java Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298060/spark-scala-datasets-using-java-classes)